# Validating Empty column of .csv file in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to fetch data from .csv file using Bash Shell script and i want to validate a column in shell script. It is not going inside the `if` block. But when i had used echo command it is null that mean it is having no value but when i am using

```
if [ -z "${Upper}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is empty"
fi
```

It is not going inside the `if` block.
Any help is most welcomed.

Comment: For checking whether the string is empty i usually use if [ "${Upper}" = "" ]; then echo "empty" fi

Comment: `if` is not a loop. How do you populate the Upper variable? You have not given us enough detail to provide any meaningful help to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the echo prints `${Upper}` blank, probably it contains only a space or a tab, change the `if` this way

```
if [[ "${Upper}" =~ '^[[:blank:]]*$' ]]; then
  echo "VAR is empty"
fi
```

Comment: while read Lower Upper
do
if [[ "$Upper" = "" ]]; then
  echo "Missing value "
else
echo "Else part"
fi

Comment: This is the code which i have written but still it is  not giving me the desired result

Comment: Ok, so please show also the code you use to put values in the `${Upper}` variable and a couple of rows from the csv file.